# How to convert PowerPoint presentations into a Kindle/E-reader friendly form?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, conversion, ebook, kindle

I have a lot of documents in .ppt and .pptx (blame the co-workers). I would like to read them on way home or elsewhere... when I have a little time to catch up with things. One thing I could do with the documents is cutting them together into one file. But saving that one even if a smaller version of PDF (according to Office 2010) results in a huge file.

And PDF is hardly readable on a Kindle.
I would need something .epub free, easy-on-the-device way.

Is there such a thing?
(Manually I could copy all the images down into native text and whatnot and create new presentations, save those, convert them. But that would just take a lot of time.)

Comment: Are you using office to Convert to PDF? I think MSOffice PDF export is inefficient. You may want to look into a dedicated PDF printer like bullzip. Hopefully that will allow you to minimize the size of the document, and adjust the dimensions so there's no scrolling on the kindle...

Comment: You could try using [Mobipocket Reader](http://www.mobipocket.com/en/downloadsoft/productdetailsreader.asp) to convert your PP slides to .mobi format, which is the Kindle's native format. But I'd predict that they wouldn't be any more readable than PDF's. The problem isn't format, the problem is that e-readers are just not good at displaying presentations.

Comment: I've had wildly different results with PDF on Kindle.  Some are fine, others are useless, all going through the same email-based Amazon conversion.  What makes them bad in your case?  Switching the PPT to a different color theme (higher contrast, fewer grayscale values) might help.  Changing the PDF options in the Save As PDF dialog box might give you smaller PDFs, as would deleting images (which'll look blech on the kindle anyhow) prior to conversion.  That, at least, would be easy to automate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to run conversion from .pdf to .mobi through [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com).

This may help.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you can do is to convert your powerpoint file to pdf then read that through calibre.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file as RTF which is [supported by Kindle](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200767340). It's a rich text format like DOC or DOCX, hence can reflow easily. However if the file contains a lot of images then the layout may break

[image: PowerPoint]