# How to convert a power point pdf to a pdf that is easy to read on kindle?

Tags: pdf, printing, conversion, presentations, kindle

I have several power point presentations as pdfs. I would like to read them on the original kindle in landscape format. When I read the original on the kindle then a single slide won't fit on the kindles display.

I thought the easiest way to convert the pdf was to repring it with a pdf printer. However I don't know the paper size to use.

I already tried using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) as suggested by [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/502040/how-to-convert-powerpoint-presentations-into-a-kindle-e-reader-friendly-form). However the output is not usable because of formatting issues.

So what paper size should I use for the pdf printer to reprint them in landscape format or are there any other tools I could use for that task?

Comment: PDF is a printed format. (e.g. when you create the PDF you already decide how wide your paper/kindle display is going to be). This is not very flexible. What you really want is to save the text/presentation in a non-printed format where the device can adjust the output (e.g. as HTML, rich text or any of the native ebooks format. There **is** a reason they created these formats.)

Comment: @Hennes I'm aware of that, but that just won't work for the slides I want to read on the kindle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reprinted them with a pdf printer for paper size 129mmx90mm. With that size each slides fits on the kindle display.